# Two battery icons after installing "Jupiter" applet, but only in one account

Tags: jupiter

I have three accounts set up on my netbook, and the Jupiter applet installed to help with battery life.  However, on my main account (my account) the Jupiter applet has a battery indicator next to it, as well as the regular battery  icon next to the mail icon.

There is another "Administrator" account on the netbook, yet that account doesn't have the extra battery icon.  Any idea why or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've installed a utility called `dconf-editor` and fixed this problem. Install it in the Software Center (the package is called `dconf-tools`). Run it, and there is the option on the left: 'desktop'----'Unity'----'Panel'. Click 'set to default' under that. Log out and back in. The problem should be fixed!